# How to ignore files when creating PR from dev to release branch in github web

Tags: git, github

Can anyone help if there is a way to let GitHub ignore changes in specific files while creating a PR from develop to release branch?

I tried adding the file in .gitattributes but I still see the file in PR changes.

My .gitattributes file.

[image]

When I create a PR I see the file is showing up.
[image]

Comment: If you're creating a new PR from your own fork, then just exclude those files or lines or hunks when you're staging your changes when you creating your commits. How are you creating your commits? Are you familiar with git's line/hunk/file staging capabilities and/or are you using a git GUI that lets you stage/unstage individual lines, hunks and files? (Annoyingly Visual Studio does not let you stage/unstage individual lines, grrr)

Comment: No not from my own fork. The use case is let's say a PR from upstream/develop to upstream/release.

Answer (score 1):

*You* created this commit. When you did, *you* included the modified version of this file in the commit. Now you are trying to merge (that is what a pull request is, it's a merge), and git sees the file in this commit is different from the "same" file at the end of the branch you are merging with. So it takes that into account as part of the merge.

If you don't want this change to be part of the commit, don't include the change made in that file in this branch. On your branch, make a commit that *reverts* the change, and push. Now the pull request will see that the file is *the same* as the "same" file at the end of the branch you are merging with, and it won't need to alter the file as part of the merge.

As for `.gitignore`, it is irrelevant at this point. You have already shown git this file by making it part of a commit; henceforth, it will not ignore it. You can ask it to disregard future changes to this file when you make new commits henceforth, but that has nothing to do with `.gitignore`.